# How can I send data throught USB in Android?

Tags: android, usb

I am develope android app and i would like send data throught USB port.

My code:

```
    manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();


    mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);

    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();

    String i = "Test: ";
    while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
        device = deviceIterator.next();
        manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);
        i += "\n" + "DeviceID: " + device.getDeviceId() + "\n"
                + "DeviceName: " + device.getDeviceName() + "\n"
                + "DeviceClass: " + device.getDeviceClass() + " - "
                + "DeviceSubClass: " + device.getDeviceSubclass() + "\n"
                + "VendorID: " + device.getVendorId() + "\n"
                + "ProductID: " + device.getProductId() + "\n"
                + device.getInterface(0) + " ";

    }

    String a = "VOLT120[CR]";

    byte[] bytes = a.getBytes();
    int TIMEOUT = 0;
    boolean forceClaim = true;

    UsbInterface intf = device.getInterface(0);
    UsbEndpoint endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);
    UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(device);
    connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);
    connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, bytes, bytes.length, TIMEOUT); 

    connection.close();

    textv.setText(i);
```

I can read some information from device, but when i send some data, the app fall down and I dont know why. Can someone tell me, where is the problem?

Comment: What exception/error are you seeing?

Comment: That was the problem. I dont know, because I dont know how to debug it, because, I dont have connected mobile to PC.

Comment: Well, you *could* add some exception handling/logging to your code as a start; I'm assuming also that the USB device you're trying to talk to isn't the PC...

Comment: java.lang.SecurityException: User has not given permission to device UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/001/002]


Do you know, how can I give permission to device?